# Update sub item in ListView according to item selected in Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I would like to update the subItem text with the item selected in different activity. How can this is solved?

Actually here is what I am trying to do:

I have listView called MainListview with different Headings (daily use, Veggies, car Stuff). I am trying to set subitem text according to the item selected in subItem activity

Something similar to picture:

[image]

If I click Veggies (Another activity with Listview and check box is opened there I select tomato and Potatoe and click OK. I should get tomato, Potatoe in subitem instead right now all the sub item shows the same values Totmato, Potatoe

how can achieve the above logic?

Can somebody help me with this?

Right now: I am doing soemthing like this:

```
 listofitems = new itemDetails(iTemName, subitemtext.toString());
 listofitemByList.add(listofitems);

 adapter = new ItemListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_row, listofitemByList);
 list.setAdapter(adapter);
```

And I get the following wrong results in MainListView:

[image]

Thanks!

MainActivity which gets the mainListView Items from API.

```
private void callFilterItems() 
{
    final RequestParams requestParams = new RequestParams();

    pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
    casevalue = pref.getString("category", getResources().getString(R.string.all));

    requestParams.put("CategoryURL", casevalue);


    final String uploadWebsite = getResources().getString(R.string.allitemlink);

    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.post(uploadWebsite, requestParams, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) 
        {
            listofitemBylist.clear();

            try 
            {
                details = response.getJSONArray(TAG_DETAIL);
                for (int i = 0; i < details.length(); i++) 
                {
                    JSONObject c = details.getJSONObject(i);

                    Log.e("Value","Of C"+c);

                    iTemName = c.getString(TAG_ITEM_NAME);
                    for (int j = 0; j < dbe.getCountValue(); j++)
                    {
                    text = dbe.getsubmenuitemnamechecked().get(j).getmenuID();
                        subMenuItemtext = sb.append(text+", ");

                listofitems = new itemDetails(iTemName, subMenuItemtext .toString());
 listofitemByList.add(listofitems);


            }

        } 
        catch (JSONException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        pDialog.dismiss();

 adapter = new ItemListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.list_row, listofitemByList);
 list.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

My CUSTOM ADAPTER:

```
   public class ItemListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<itemDetails>
  {
ArrayList<ItemDetails> itemList;
private ArrayList<ItemDetails> originalList;
private LayoutInflater vi;
private Context context;
private SharedPreferences pref;
private String filtername;


private String text;
private int count;

public ItemListAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<ItemDetails> nameList) 
{
    super(context, textViewResourceId, nameList);
    this.itemList = new ArrayList<ItemDetails>();
    this.itemList.addAll(nameList);

    this.originalList = new ArrayList<ItemDetails>();
    this.originalList.addAll(nameList);
    this.context = context;

    vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

private class ViewHolder
{
    public TextView itemName;
    public TextView itemsubtext;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() 
{
    if (filter == null)
    {
        filter  = new FriendsFilter();
    }
    return filter;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) 
{

    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.itemName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemListName);
        holder.itemsubtext = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemListsubName);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    FilterDetails pd = itemList.get(position);
    holder.filterName.setText(pd.getfilterName());
    holder.filterenabled.setText(pd.getsubItem());

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Anybody who can help me with issue? i am struggling to a get the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can tell you the logic, you have to implement it yourself. Use Hashmap. Your key(string) in hashmap will be main listview's heading (daily use, veggies etc). Value to corresponding string will be Arraylist that will contain child items.
According to pics key in Hashmap will be "veggies" and corresponding Arraylist will contain checked items ("potato" ,"tomato" etc).
**You do not need to have multiple textviews in Main listview for different items**
Ex- 
Textview1 - potato
Textview2 - tomato
This approach do not have any advantage.

**Just make One textview for subitems(Arraylist items) and set their values to that textview**

```
Textview t;
```

Initialize it somewhere then

```
t.setText("tomato"
+","
+"potato"
+","
+"next item in corresponding arraylist");
```

Comment: Right now I have arraylist.. So you are asking me to have arraylist of hashmap?

Comment: No. Please tell me what data your arraylist contains.

Comment: Arraylist contains the headers and storing the submenu items in the database.

Comment: Where you want to add textview

Comment: actually I am looking for a work around that can help me solve the issue. Hence asked if I can manually add textview and set text accordingly

Comment: Please check my updated question you might get an idea on what I am getting now and what I am looking for ?

Comment: Can you post code of adapter and mainlist activity, i'll solve it. There are many ways to do it.

Comment: I have updated my question with code. Please take a look at it. Let me know! Thanks!  @Umesh Chhabra

Comment: Hi... Did you get some idea after looking my code. Let me know!

Comment: Post your url that return Json data . Post your json response also. Did you logged it and saw it in logcat ,whether it is correct or not ?

Comment: Yeah i got it. You are using AsyncHttpClient, you can use volley,retrofit (both are coding friendly) i do use volley library.

Comment: All Values are coming up properly but I am questions is how to update the subItem (Potatoe, Tomato) to the main listview

Comment: text = dbe.getsubmenuitemnamechecked().get(j).getmenuID();
                        subMenuItemtext = sb.append(text+", ");
   What is dbe????  May be that is the problem and you are getting same string. Post json response also.

Comment: I think you are updating same fields from submenu, and getting last submenu updated.

Comment: In table make rows for menuitems eg  id(primary), mainitem(unique) ,subitem ///////////////////1st row will be  //////// id(1) mainitem(daily use) subitem("toothpaste, soap, bread)////////  2nd row ////////  id(2) mainitem(veggies) subitem("potato, tomato")

Comment: Update row according to mainitems when checkboxes change

Comment: I have created the tables but how do I update the subItems? How will I know which MainItem has been clicked?

Comment: list.setOnItemClickListener

Comment: Hey! Didn't get you? Can you come again?

Comment: Use onItemClickListener to know which item is clicked